# SQL Server displaying two rows data to a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `ID`, `Address` and `Type` and data as follows

```
1 ADD1 1
1 Add2 2
2 Add1 1
2 Add2 2
```

Using a query how can I get the data as follows:

Columns

```
ID Addess1 Address2

1 Add1 Add2
2 Add1 Add2
```

Using the third column `Type`,

- if the `Type` is 1 the corresponding `Address` should be placed in `Add1` column
- if the `Type` is 2 the corresponding `Address` should be placed in `Add2` column

Please suggest how to write the query for the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be like this:

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Type = 1
                THEN Address
                ELSE '' END AS Add1,
           CASE WHEN Type = 2
                THEN Address
                ELSE '' END AS Add2
FROM tbl
```

Another option might be something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Address AS Add1, '' AS Add2
FROM tbl
WHERE Type = 1
UNION
SELECT ID, '' AS Add1, Address AS Add2
FROM tbl
WHERE Type = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ColumnID, 
CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN Address1 ELSE '' END AS Add1,
CASE Type WHEN 2 THEN Address1 ELSE '' END AS Add2
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using just SQL to query the server and get the data then you would use something like the SQL code provided in @neoistheone answer

If you are accessing the database from within a program written in VB.NET for example you could use a stored procedure and pass the `TYPE` as a parameter. See sample code below:

`ResetParameters()
CreateParameter("Type", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar,ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10, Type)
RunSP("spx_Select_Data", "GlobalRS")`

And then loop to display the data like so:

`If not GlobalRS.EOF then
   Grid.Rows.Add(CFN(GlobalrS("ID").Value), CFN(GlobalrS("Address").Value))
   GlobalRS.MoveNext();
End If`

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COLUMNID, 
MAX(CASE TYPE WHEN 1 THEN ADDRESS1 ELSE '' END) AS ADD1,
MAX(CASE TYPE WHEN 2 THEN ADDRESS1 ELSE '' END) AS ADD2
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMNID